# Are questions about poultry birds on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I want to know if questions about poultry birds like (chicken, turkey, etc) on topic for [Pets](http://pets.stackexchange.com)?.

The reason form my question is, in my opinion these poultry birds are not usually kept as pets but mainly for other purpose like food, laying eggs, sale.

So are questions about poultry birds on topic for Pets?

Comment: Some people have such a strong bond with their chicken, they can't bear being away from it. So science has come to the rescue and invented a [remote chicken hugger](http://www.engadget.com/2005/04/04/you-got-to-know-your-chicken-and-you-can-do-it-through-the-web/). Hell, yes, chickens are on topic!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think they should be.

At this stage, I *don't* think we should harass people too much over the *according-to-Hoyle* definition of a "pet." Definitions will vary by culture, and frankly I don't see this site being overrun by chicken questions.

Generally speaking, I think it's okay to keep it simply stated: **"This site welcomes questions by individuals generally seeking to provide personal care of a domestic animal."** That's in contrast to, say, industrial methods for rearing of animals for agricultural use, or zoological veterinary issues, etc.

Yes, there will always be a middle ground where someone raises a few chickens for eggs, or a calf becomes a pet, or a working horse gets ridden on the weekends — but in general, I think if we take a lighter approach to moderation of these questions, you'll know when the quasi-industrial questions are simply outside the expertise we've gathered here. Until then, just enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination

Comment: Nicely said. It also kind talks to the ideas we've been batting about with respect to livestock.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are in the world, they may very well be pets, other place it would be very unlikely. One, unfortunate I think, habit in North America is parents getting baby chicks for kids as Easter gifts. They're cute as chicks, a little less so as full-grown chickens. Nevertheless, they are pets in that case.

Comment: I guess so. In my country they are hardly used as pets

Answer (score 0):

I would say, yes, in general, they are on topic, as you shouldn't automatically exclude any species as a pet.  We don't want agriculture questions here from professional chicken operations, but chickens can be pets, even if the owner collects eggs from them.